# Red Pitaya WiFi adapter Edimax EW7811U

Tags: redpitaya

This is a comment to a previously asked question related to the EW7811U WiFi adapter (the topic was closed so I cannot answer directly). I have the same Edimax EW7811U adapter and here is how I got it working with Red Pitaya and my WPA2-protected 802.11n network.

First shut off the Red Pitaya, remove the memory card and connect it to a PC (I used the adapter that came with the memory card and inserted into the memory card slot in my laptop).

Edit the file /etc/network/wpa_supplicant.conf and insert the ssid and psk strings:

```
# WPA2 configuration example
network={
   ssid="ssid-string"
   psk="password-string"
   proto=WPA2
   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
   pairwise=CCMP
   group=CCMP
   auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Save the file and put the memory card back into Red Pitaya and restart.

In my console I can see that the wlan0 interface is initialized and that the DHCP client gets an IP address:

```
++ Bringing up wlan0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
udhcpc (v1.20.1) started
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
Sending select for 192.168.11.115...
Lease of 192.168.11.115 obtained, lease time 43200
```

You can check the interface status with iwconfig:

```
redpitaya> iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"my-ssid"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 20:C9:D0:1D:AB:CD   
      Bit Rate:150 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=83/100  Noise level=0/100
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: One additional note: you can actually edit the files directly by making the file system writable with the 'rw' command (use 'ro' to make it read-only after edits).

Comment: You can skip all this given the recent updates and bug fixes for the Red Pitaya. Just follow the quick-start instructions exactly, choosing the "connect wirelessly" option. Note that you must restart the Red Pitaya twice like it says.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an answer to a question posted elsewhere and not a question in itself. In addition, it is off topic here which is why the referenced question was closed. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)